# undo set system static-host-mapping

Tags: linux, macos, shell, oh-my-zsh

Help

I was trying to set a static map for 'home' on my mac so I didnt have to type the ip and port all the time in chrome.

I used the command:

```
set system static-host-mapping home inst 192.168.1.100:8123
```

Now entering home or the ip give a 'Page isnt working' error.  How to I undo this?

Im using oh-my-zsh shell in iterm2 on macbook pro (2017)

Thanks
Paul

Comment: NB I have tried the 'show system' and 'delete system' commands, they are not recognied as valid commands

Answer (score 1):

Solved it myself

```
set system static-host-mapping home inet
```